# IS there a python code to implement Fayad and Irani's Entropy based discretization?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

i want to get a python code to implement Fayad and Irani's Entropy based discretization.
please help me.

Comment: You want us to find it for you? That's explicitly off-topic. You want us to write it for you? Ditto. If you have made an attempt and got stuck, give a [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

Three pythonic ways in which continuous variables/features can be discretized using a supervised method - MDLP by Fayyad, U.; Irani, K.

**Assumptions**

Input Data : X

target : y

categorical_features: Categorical columns that need not be discretized

1. [Orange](https://docs.biolab.si//3/data-mining-library/_modules/Orange/preprocess/discretize.html#EntropyMDL)

   ```
   import Orange
   continuous_features = [*set(X.columns)-set(categorical_features)]
   X[categorical_features] = X[categorical_features].astype('category')
   data_df = pd.concat([X[continuous_features ], y.astype('category')], axis=1)
   orange_table = table_from_frame(data_df, class_name=data_df.colum[-1])  
   disc = Orange.preprocess.Discretize()
   disc.method = Orange.preprocess.discretize.EntropyMDL()
   orange_table_discrete = disc(orange_table)
   X[continuous_features ] = orange_table_discrete.X
   ```
2. [Pypi package](https://pypi.org/project/mdlp-discretization/)

   ```
   from mdlp.discretization import MDLP
   transformer = MDLP(continuous_features=[True if x not in categorical_features else False for x in X.columns])
   X = pd.DataFrame(transformer.fit_transform(X, y), columns=X.columns)
   ```
3. [Github repo](https://github.com/maxpumperla/entropy-mdlp/blob/master/entropymdlp/mdlp.py)

   ```
   from entropymdlp import MDLP
   mdlp = MDLP()
   for col in X[continous_fetures].columns:
       bins = mdlp.cut_points(X[col].values, y.values)
       X[col] = mdlp.discretize_feature(X[col], bins)
       X[col] = np.where(X[col].isnull(), np.nan, X[col])
   ```

To check discretization count of each column/feature

```
    print(X.T.apply(lambda x: x.nunique(), axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [this method](https://orange.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/rst/Orange.feature.discretization.html#Orange.feature.discretization.Entropy) in [orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) ML platform.
It seems to be based on [Fayyad and Irani](https://orange.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/rst/Orange.feature.discretization.html#fayyadirani93).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one here: https://github.com/navicto/Discretization-MDLPC

I haven't check it in detail, though.